# How to restore a single file from a package?

Tags: package-management

How can I do this without reinstalling the rest of the files as well?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Download the package, for example `transmission-daemon`, with

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install transmission-daemon
```

unpack the package with

```
mkdir ~/dummy
dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/transmission-daemon_*.deb ~/dummy
```

restore the file, for example `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`

```
sudo cp ~/dummy/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon /etc/init.d
```

remove the dir

```
rm -rf ~/dummy
```

Comment: It should also be noted that `apt-get download` downloads to the current working directory `.`

Comment: You can avoid extracting the entire archive using a pipeline involving `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile` and `tar`, like so: `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile "$package"*.deb | tar -x ./path/to/file`

Comment: `/tmp/dummy` seems more convenient that `~/dummy` and the need to remove it.

Comment: Prefer `apt-get download` since `apt-get --download-only install` will stop if the package is already installed. As indicated by camypaj's answer.

Comment: To expand on kojiro's comment, I had to look at what's the default value of `nginx`'s `worker_processes` setting on a range of machines. So I came up with the following command: `for f in /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common*; do dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile "$f" | tar xO ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep worker_processes; done`.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is a bit old, but here's my improvement:

```
$ sudo apt-get download <package-name>
```

instead of

```
$ sudo apt-get --download-only install <package-name>
```

I had a situation where the package was already installed (hence, the proposed solution didn't work), and I wanted to restore just one config file, in order to fix the problem.

Cheers

Comment: if you have a package already installed then it's typically found in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and you shouldn't have to download it.

Comment: Yes, but only if the package was installed relatively recently, and the archives have not been manually or automatically cleaned.

Comment: The alternative would be to add `--reinstall` to the `--download-only` mode. Then the package will be downloaded even if it had been already installed.