# Accidentally Deleted apache2.conf what can I do?

Tags: apache2

I deleted `apache.conf` with command `rm /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` so what are my options? How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two possible solutions

1. Uninstall and reinstall apache server
2. Find the specific file and paste it in the required directory. You can find one [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/ssllabs/mailman/attachment/50818B5B.2000805%40KingsMountain.com/1/)

Comment: The page url is broken

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the same file back you may have to use some sort of recovery software.

If not, this will do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  apache2 apache2-utils
```

Comment: To find out **name of the package** containing this file: `dpkg -S /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. See also: [How to restore a single file from a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37156/how-to-restore-a-single-file-from-a-package)