# Accidentally deleted the ipsec.conf file - what to do now?

Tags: vpn, 17.10, ipsec

While trying to setup my L2TP/IPSec VPN with strongswan and the network-manager-l2tp on Ubuntu 17.10 I accidentally deleted the `ipsec.conf` file from `/etc`.

Reinstalling strongswan didn't help to recreate the `ipsec.conf` file. How should I proceed if I still want to configure a L2TP/IPSec VPN connection?

Comment: There is a sample `ipsec.conf` file on this page: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/UsableExamples that would perhaps serve as a starting point? Another more basic example here: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecConf

Comment: Thank you for the different example files. Two follow up questions: 1) Which configuration is most appropriate for me if my use case is just connecting to a server (these files get really technical quickly so I have hard times understanding them)? Is there something like a default file? 2) If I try to save one of the sample setups using the Text Editor, I get the error message that I don't have the permission to save the file in `~/etc`. How do I solve this? If I create a file in `~/etc` using `touch ipsec.conf` the resulting file is read-only.

Comment: OK I have sorted out a method to retrieve the standard Ubuntu package config file, I will post this as an answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [reasonably straightforward](https://askubuntu.com/q/37156/57576) to retrieve the required conf file from the 17.10 Ubuntu package. Use the following steps from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install strongswan
mkdir -v $HOME/testing
dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/strongswan-starter_5.5.1-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb $HOME/testing
sudo cp -v $HOME/testing/etc/ipsec.conf /etc
```

This places the configuration file correctly in /etc and from here you will need to use *elevated privileges* (sudo) to edit the file using your favoured text editor. Once you are happy the testing directory can be safely removed:

```
rm -rfv $HOME/testing
```

The Ubuntu file is by default completely commented out but it gives 2 simple examples, either of which could be a great start for you:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no

# Add connections here.

# Sample VPN connections

#conn sample-self-signed
#      leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
#      leftcert=selfCert.der
#      leftsendcert=never
#      right=192.168.0.2
#      rightsubnet=10.2.0.0/16
#      rightcert=peerCert.der
#      auto=start

#conn sample-with-ca-cert
#      leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
#      leftcert=myCert.pem
#      right=192.168.0.2
#      rightsubnet=10.2.0.0/16
#      rightid="C=CH, O=Linux strongSwan CN=peer name"
#      auto=start
```

Activate these settings by removing the '#' mark at the beginning of each line and then hopefully all will be well.

Comment: @goldenoslik My pleasure and have a great day :)