# How to get binary file of a package without installing it?

Tags: apt, package-management

I know that binary files of installed packages are present in the /bin folder but I want to access binary files of a package without installing it for my project, is there a method to do so? Like can I access them from package files? I am downloading packages [from here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) Also, I am new to working with Linux (ubuntu binaries) so any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `dpkg-deb -x` to extract files from a .deb archive locally. See for example [How to restore a single file from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/a/37157/178692). I'd suggest `apt download` in place of `apt-get --download-only install` to make the download local as well though.

Comment: Ok, after doing this I get three directories, <pacakge-name>, lib, and share. I am unable to locate the binary file in these directories. Where can I get it?

Comment: how are we supposed to guess? you haven't told us what binary, what package, or even what version of Ubuntu you are using

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused here. Can you please explain the relationship between binary and its package? Binary is what we get after installing a package, right? Can one package have more than one binary? It would be really helpful.

Comment: A package may contain more than one binary (think of the `coreutils` package for example) or none at all (e.g. `manpages`, or a dependency-only package such as `gcc`).

Comment: Ok, got it thanks!